# Clip a texture with correct UVs inside a deformed rectangle in WebGL / Threejs

Tags: three.js, glsl, shader, webgl

Hey I am trying to make a clipped texture inside a frame effect like this. The idea is that the frame can be freely wrapped and transformed around, while the texture remains correctly sampled, hence the "portal" or "frame" effect I am referring to:

[image: image of desired wrapped effect]

Here is my code snippet with the relevant JS and shader code:

```js
const photoUrl = 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1583287916880-530d57049c66?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&w=400&fit=max&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjE0NTg5fQ'

const appWidth = innerWidth
const appHeight = innerHeight

const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer()
const camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera(appWidth / - 2, appWidth / 2, appHeight / 2, appHeight / - 2, 1, 1000)
const scene = new THREE.Scene()

camera.position.set(0, 0, 50)
camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0))

renderer.setClearColor(0xAAAAAA)
renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio || 1)
renderer.setSize(appWidth, appHeight)
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement)

const vertexShader = `
varying vec2 v_uv;
void main () {

  vec3 newPosition = position;
  float dist = distance(position, vec3(0.0));
  newPosition.x += sin(3.0) * dist * 3.0;
  // newPosition.y += cos(0.1) * dist * 0.2;
  gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(newPosition, 1.0);
  v_uv = uv;

  // I guess do some magic with v_uv to inverse transform it based on the vertices transformation??

}
`
const fragmentShader = `
uniform sampler2D u_sampler;
uniform vec2 u_imageSize;
varying vec2 v_uv;

void main () {
  vec2 s = vec2(250.0, 400.0);
  vec2 i = u_imageSize;
  float rs = s.x / s.y;
  float ri = i.x / i.y;
  vec2 new = rs < ri ? vec2(i.x * s.y / i.y, s.y) : vec2(s.x, i.y * s.x / i.x);
  vec2 offset = (rs < ri ? vec2((new.x - s.x) / 2.0, 0.0) : vec2(0.0, (new.y - s.y) / 2.0)) / new;
  vec2 uv = v_uv * s / new + offset;
  // sample texture like css background-size: cover
  // OR if the texture is the same size as plane, apply some matrix transform to UVs so there is extra padding and you dont see the texture corners when the plane is deformed at maximum?
  gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_sampler, uv);
}
`

const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(
  new THREE.PlaneGeometry(250, 400, 20, 20),
  new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
    uniforms: {
      u_sampler: { value: null },
      u_imageSize: { value: new THREE.Vector2(0, 0) },
    },
    vertexShader,
    fragmentShader,
  })
)
scene.add(mesh)

new THREE.TextureLoader().load(photoUrl, texture => {
  mesh.material.uniforms.u_sampler.value = texture
  mesh.material.uniforms.u_imageSize.value.x = texture.image.naturalWidth
  mesh.material.uniforms.u_imageSize.value.y = texture.image.naturalHeight
  mesh.material.needsUpdate = true
})

updateFrame()
function updateFrame () {
  renderer.render(scene, camera)
  requestAnimationFrame(updateFrame)
}
```

```css
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/110/three.min.js"></script>
```

As expected, this produces a plane with both vertices positions and UVs wrapped. I am struggling to wrap my head around the math and order of operations behind it. Thanks in advance!

P.S. Additionally, if I use a texture thats exactly the same as my plane in terms of pixel size (I use orthographic camera), I guess I need to upscale it to expand beyond the plane's borders, so when the plane is transformed you dont see its edges / bleeding? How should one go about that?

Comment: Is there some reason you didn't use a [snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)?

Comment: @gman, no reason at all, just an oversight on my part. I updated my question using a snippet. Your insight is more then welcome, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original formula for vUv is

```
v_uv.x = position.x/width+0.5;
```

Since you have changed the position. It now becomes,

```
v_uv.x = newPosition.x/width+0.5;
```

```js
const photoUrl = 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1583287916880-530d57049c66?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&w=400&fit=max&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjE0NTg5fQ'

const appWidth = innerWidth
const appHeight = innerHeight

const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer()
const camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera(appWidth / - 2, appWidth / 2, appHeight / 2, appHeight / - 2, 1, 1000)
const scene = new THREE.Scene()

camera.position.set(0, 0, 50)
camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0))

renderer.setClearColor(0xAAAAAA)
renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio || 1)
renderer.setSize(appWidth, appHeight)
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement)

const vertexShader = `
varying vec2 v_uv;
uniform vec2 u_imageSize;
void main () {

  vec3 newPosition = position;
  float dist = distance(position, vec3(0.0));
  newPosition.x += sin(3.0) * dist * 3.0;
  newPosition.y += cos(0.1) * dist * 0.2;
  gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(newPosition, 1.0);
  v_uv = uv;
  //v_uv.x = position.x/250.0+0.5;
  //v_uv.y = position.y/400.0+0.5;
  v_uv.x = newPosition.x/250.0+0.5;
  v_uv.y = newPosition.y/400.0+0.5;
}
`
const fragmentShader = `
uniform sampler2D u_sampler;
uniform vec2 u_imageSize;
varying vec2 v_uv;

void main () {
  vec2 s = vec2(250.0, 400.0);
  vec2 i = u_imageSize;
  float rs = s.x / s.y;
  float ri = i.x / i.y;
  vec2 new = rs < ri ? vec2(i.x * s.y / i.y, s.y) : vec2(s.x, i.y * s.x / i.x);
  vec2 offset = (rs < ri ? vec2((new.x - s.x) / 2.0, 0.0) : vec2(0.0, (new.y - s.y) / 2.0)) / new;
  vec2 uv = v_uv * s / new + offset;
  // sample texture like css background-size: cover
  // OR if the texture is the same size as plane, apply some matrix transform to UVs so there is extra padding and you dont see the texture corners when the plane is deformed at maximum?
  gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_sampler, uv);
}
`

const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(
  new THREE.PlaneGeometry(250, 400, 20, 20),
  new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
    uniforms: {
      u_sampler: { value: null },
      u_imageSize: { value: new THREE.Vector2(0, 0) },
    },
    vertexShader,
    fragmentShader,
  })
)
scene.add(mesh)

new THREE.TextureLoader().load(photoUrl, texture => {
  mesh.material.uniforms.u_sampler.value = texture
  mesh.material.uniforms.u_imageSize.value.x = texture.image.naturalWidth
  mesh.material.uniforms.u_imageSize.value.y = texture.image.naturalHeight
  mesh.material.needsUpdate = true
})

updateFrame()
function updateFrame () {
  renderer.render(scene, camera)
  requestAnimationFrame(updateFrame)
}
```

```css
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/110/three.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thank a lot, this make sense. so `v_uv.x = newPosition.x/width+0.5;`  (and vice versa for y) is generic approach to calculating uvs in vertex shader? i didnt know this trick :)